# Exercise involving $\Sigma$ notation

Tags: statistics, summation, means

Determine if the following statements are true, false, uncertain, where $\bar z$ is the simple average of $z_i$ and state any necessary assumptions:

a) $\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\bar Y = \bar X \bar Y$

b)$\sum_{i=1}^N X_iY_i = \bar X \bar Y$

c)$\sum_{i=1}^N X_i^2 = \bar X^2$

d)$\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1,j\neq i}^N X_iY_j = (X_1\sum_{j=1,j\neq i}^N Y_j + X_2\sum_{j=1,j\neq i}^NY_j +...+X_N\sum_{j=1,j\neq i}^NY_j)$

I figured a) I believe: 
$$\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\bar Y =\bar Y \left(\frac NN \right) \sum_{i=1}^N X_i = \bar X \bar Y$$
and I am also sure that b) is false, since you cannot expand multiplication like this.

Could you please help to deal with the following question? Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? If you don't include this, the vibe I personally get is that you simply want someone to do your homework for you, rather than learning something, but I hope that this is not the case. Please edit your question accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: I am very sorry if I create this impression, but I am new to this site and I struggle with putting formulas in properly. I believe I got a) and I would love to show what I have, but I have no idea how to put in formulas. So, I have sigma(xiYbar)=Ybar(N/N)sigma(xi)=XbarYbar.

Sorry :c

Comment: No problem, welcome to the site! Check out [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to get a hold of it (most of it is simply enclosing your math by dollar-signs, it is not as hard as it perhaps seems). Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much! Seems like I figured it out. So for I have a) $\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\bar Y =\bar Y (\frac NN) \sum_{i=1}^N X_i = \bar X \bar Y$. And I am also sure that b) is not right, since you cannot expand it like this.

Comment: If you think it is not true, why don't you try to find a counter-example? Make up a few $X_i,Y_i$ (for instance for $N=2$) and check if the equations are true.

Comment: [Sigma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma) not [Stigma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stigma_(letter)) </pedant>.  And I suspect you should have $\frac1N$ somewhere

Comment: There are no equations, unfortunately. It's an exercise that helps to solve for regressors and it's main purpose is to teach us to work with Sigma notations.

Comment: @Henry I looked at the example we did in the class, and we do this because $\bar X$ is a sample mean, and $\bar X=\frac 1N \sum_{i=1}^N X_i$.

Answer (score 0):

For a) 
$$\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\bar Y =\bar Y \sum_{i=1}^N X_i= \bar Y (N\bar X)\not= \bar X \bar Y.$$
If you have forgot a factor $\frac{1}{N}$, then it would be true.

b) is false both since the factor $N^{-2}$ is missing and since you cannot expand like that, as you say (all the cross-terms are missing).

c) is false, since the variance per definition would otherwise always be zero (again, a factor $\frac{1}{N}$ is probably missing).

Regarding d), what do you think? Let me know in a comment and I'll tell you if it is right or wrong.

*And good job figuring out the MathJax!*